# C print space pyramid

Tags: c

I want to print this:

```
***********
***** *****
****   ****
***     ***
**       **
*         *
```

but instead I get this:

```
     ****
*    ***
**   **
***  *
****
```

Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int rows,i,j,space;

    rows = 5;
    //printf("Enter number of rows: ");
    //scanf("%d",&rows);
    for(i=rows;i>=1;--i)
    {
        for(space=0;space<rows-i;++space)
           printf("*");
        for(j=i;j<=2*i-1;++j)
          printf(" ");
        for(j=0;j<i-1;++j)
            printf(" ");
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

What is wrong with this? Can anyone help me? I have tried many options but none of them prints what I want. Thanks

Comment: Walk us through what your loops are supposed to be doing. To me it looks like you print some number of stars, print some number of spaces, print more spaces and then newline. Which means there's no way to get that star space star figure you have up top.

Comment: If you need to print *s around your spaces, then a good start would be to have two places printing *. Right now, you only print them once

Comment: The third (inner) loop should print a `*`.

Comment: Why all the down votes?  The questioner posted his code, the expected result and what he is getting....

Comment: Why has your current output been edited to be so radically different? NB `rows = 5` but your required output has 6 rows. Downvoted since you apparently don't know either what you are getting *or* what you want.

Comment: A suggestion: abandon the `i, j, k` variables here and just use "row", "star", and "space" as your loop variables. It will clarify things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple things wrong here.

First let's address your third loop. The program should print stars, spaces, and then stars again, so that third loop shouldn't be printing spaces. Also, we're printing the same amount of stars on either side of the spaces, so the third loop will actually just be the **same exact code** as your first loop!

Secondly, here in the header of the second loop:

```
for(j=i;j<=2*i-1;++j)
```

You're missing parenthises. By the order of operations, this will evaluate as `(2*i)-1`, which isn't what you want.

There is also a tricky caveat here! You'll notice in the first row of your example output there's an ***odd number*** of stars, while every other line has an even number! In the first line only, we need to print exactly one less star! Which means we'll need this code in one of our star loops to ignore the first star of the first row:

```
if(i !=0 || space != 0) printf("*");
```

Lastly, I've flipped your outer loop to iterate the other way, as it looked like that was what you wanted and it helped to solve some other problems:

```
for(i=0;i<rows;++i)
{
    for(space=0;space<rows-i;++space)
       if(i!=0 || space != 0) printf("*");
    for(j=0;j<2*(i-1)+1;++j)
      printf(" ");
    for(space=0;space<rows-i;++space)
       printf("*");
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: This works but I need the reverse of this. See the pic in my question. @scohe001

Comment: @rexhin have you checked what my program [outputs](http://ideone.com/WhW1Ci)? That looks like the picture you have...and if not, just flip the outer loop!

Answer (score 2):

Did you modify this from a program which originally was supposed to have spaces and asterisks the other way around? You forgot to change the other space-printing loop to print asterisks… =)

```
    for(space=0;space<rows-i;++space) // <- name of variable misleading
       printf("*"); // <- ok
    for(j=i;j<=2*i-1;++j)
      printf(" "); // <- ok
    for(j=0;j<i-1;++j) // <- this should print as many *'s as the first loop
      printf(" "); // <- ???
```

**edit**: re. modified question, the loops themselves are also slightly wrong. You have all the pieces required to fix it, tweak the termination conditions of the loops and you'll get the answer.

As an additional observation, all of your `printf` calls are printing only one character each, so you could replace them with, e.g., `putchar`.

Comment: Yes I did that. Check my updated question. The left half is one level below  and reversed. @Arkuu