# how to left align a set of characters in C

Tags: c

I am new to C and I have been trying to print a pyramid of * using for loops and printf() in a RIGHT ALIGNMENT manner; like this;

```
  *
 **
***
```

I can only do this

```
   *
   **
   ***
```

Comment: `printf("%3s", "*");printf("%3s", "**");...`

Comment: `printf("%3.1s", "***");printf("%3.2s", "***");`...`printf("%*.*s", 3, 2,"***");`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C print space pyramid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31253804/c-print-space-pyramid)

Answer (score 1):

```
#include<stdio.h>
    int main()
    {
        int i,j,k;

        for(i=1;i<=5;i++)
        {           
            for(j=5;j>i;j--)
            {
                printf(" ");
            }

            for(k=1;k<=i;k++)
            {
                printf("*");
            }

            printf("\n");
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Here the first for-loop creates rows which are 5. Second for loop does the spacing and the third for loop prints the stars.

When 
i = 1; j goes from 5 to 2 and prints spaces. After this k=1 and it prints one star.

```
i = 1; j = 5,4,3,2; k = 1
i = 2; j = 5,4,3  ; k = 1,2
.
.
i = 5; j = 0; k = 1,2,3,4,5
```

Here "-" represents a blank space.
So it goes down like this:

```
----*
---**
--***
-****
*****
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use printf format specifier tricks mentioned in the comments or you can do this using basic for loops. Break down the problem step by step. First a loop for given number of lines, then a loop for spaces in each line, then a loop for stars in each line. Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int max_stars = 3;

    // for every line
    for(int i=1; i<=max_stars; ++i){

        // print max_stars - i spaces
        for(int j=1; j<= max_stars-i; ++j){
            printf(" ");
        }

        // print i stars
        for(int j=1; j<=i; ++j){
            printf("*");
        }

        //print a new line
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Three `for` loops are not needed , if carefully analysed you can finish it with just 2.Try to achieve it.I don't wanna spoil the fun by posting the solution directly.However if help needed, you are always welcome.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void f(int n)
{
    int x = 1 , y , var ;

    while( n > 0 )
    {
        for( var = n-1 ; var > 0 ; var-- )
        {
            fputc(' ',stdout);
        }

        for( y = 0 ; y < x ; y++ )
        {
            fputc('*',stdout);
        }

        fputc('\n',stdout);

        n--;

        x++;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    f(3);

    return 0;

}
```